# disable mouse multiclick and change doubleclick interval

Tags: sdl-2

is there a way to disable multiclicks? By multiclicks I mean 3-or more clicks. I would like to have only singleClick or doubleClick. The third click should be always registered as singleClick (clicks=1). event.mouse.clicks should always be <= 2.

Another problem is the interval between clicks. If I click multiple times on the same spot between 1-2 seconds, it is always registered as a multiClick (event.mouse.clicks keeps rising). Only if I move the cursor a bit, clicks would lover to 1. How can I change this behavior so the interval between click and doubleClick will be around 1/4 second?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to have a separate thread which reads the SDL information, then do a debounce algorithm to remove the unwanted clicks. I did this for a touch screen, which is too sensitive. After filtering, you should get what you want. Then the filtered events you put in a queue (std::deque) which can be used for the real user interface to get events.

The open source project https://sourceforge.net/p/sdl2ui/wiki/Home/ has a class CdialogEvent which is may just what you need.